# $(this.el).find().click() not working in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

this is absolutely driving me crazy! Can someone please explain why this code isn't working and how to fix it? It should be sending the message "click" to the console but it is not working. Console messages work everywhere else, but for some reason javascript is not capturing the click event.

```
var resultsListView = new ResultsListView({model: comparablesList});

ResultsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:'div',
        id:'resultView',
        template:_.template("<div class='resultsListItemView'></div>"),

        initialize:function () {
            $( this.el ).html('<p class="loadingText">Getting comparables...<p>');
            this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
            this.model.bind("reset", this.loading, this);
        },

        render:function (eventName) {
            $( this.el ).html( this.template() );

            _.each(this.model.models, function (comparable) {
                this.$('.resultsListItemView').append(new ResultsListItemView({model:comparable}).el);
            }, this);

            $('#info').html($(this.el));

            return this;
        }
    });

    ResultsListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function(){
                this.render();
            },

            template:_.template("<div class='hovr_item'> \
                                    <div class='hovr'> \
                                        <button class='test123'>test</button> \
                                    </div> \
                                </div> "),

            render: function(){
                var resultsListItemView = this;
                $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

                $(this.el).find('.test123').click(function() {
                    console.log('click'); // this does not work after clicking
                });
                return this;
            }
        });
```

As an extra clue, if I put this code into render it does show up in the console... so it appears to be only the click event:

```
$(this.el).find('.test123').each(function(index) {
        console.log('found');
    });
```

Comment: It should log nothing, you first had to click the button. Can you tell us what part of the code doesn't work?

Comment: after clicking the button it doesn't log anything - i made a few edits to make the code more readable

Comment: How are you instantiating that view and how are you adding its `el` to the DOM?

Comment: added in the code for how i set it all up. let me know if you need any other info. it all renders correctly

Comment: The view stuff works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cwKT8/

Comment: hmm. so maybe its about the way its getting loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried binding this event with the events attribute? ie:

```
events: "click .test123": "affiliateClick"
```

Comment: tried this but doesnt work:
events: {
        "click .test123": "testClicked"
    },

    testClicked: function(e){
        console.log('click');
    },

Comment: Are there any other script errors on the page?  Also, try removing the trailing comma at the end of your template etc

Comment: how can i tell if there are any script errors? it all seems to run correctly. also, which commas do you mean? (sorry im a jscript newb)

Comment: If you download and install Firebug (not sure if you can get it for browsers other than FirefoX) it will show script errors and is a very useful tool for client side dev.  Also, I might just be picky about the commas because I'm so used to CoffeeScript now : )